# AngularJs Multilple Select in filter

Tags: angularjs

I'm wondering how can i create a filter with multiple options in it.

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
            enableHorizontalScrollbar: 1,
            enableFiltering: true,
            paginationPageSizes: [150, 300, 450],
            paginationPageSize: 150,
            rowHeight: 110,
            data: data,
            columnDefs: [

       {  name: 'Cars', field: 'Cars', displayName: 'Cars' , enableCellEdit: false  , width :'80' },
   {  name: 'Driver', field: 'Driver', displayName: 'Driver' , enableCellEdit: false  ,    width :'80' },
```

in case I want to filter by two types of cars , how can i do it , do you guys have any example ?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

First loop the $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs , so you get object names use that object name in your filter.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
           enableHorizontalScrollbar: 1,
           enableFiltering: true,
           paginationPageSizes: [150, 300, 450],
           paginationPageSize: 150,
           rowHeight: 110,
           data: data,
           columnDefs: [
                 {name: 'Cars', field: 'Cars', displayName: 'Cars', enableCellEdit: false, width :'80' },
                 {  name: 'Driver', field: 'Driver', displayName: 'Driver', enableCellEdit: false, width :'80' }
                ]
          };
    angular.forEach($scope.gridOptions.columnDefs, function (val, key){
         console.log(val, key);
         $scope.filterName = val.name; //use this scope variable in filter.
         console.log($scope.filterName);
      });
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I need to get like what we have in Excel, a Listbox  and then check the ones that i need to filter with :s